# What does 경 mean for sight seeing and scenery?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning, word-usage

What does 경 mean? Is there a root meaning?

경치 - scenery, view

구경하다 - to go sightseeing

Also, is there a meaning for 구 in verb (to go sightseeing) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

경 comes from the Chinese word 景, which in Modern Standard Mandarin is pronounced *jǐng*, and in Standard Cantonese *ging<sup>2</sup>*. This is also used in Japanese in its *on'yomi* reading as けい (*kei*).

On its own, this hanja is given the *eumhun* 볕 경 *gyeong* as in "sunshine/sunbeams". However, this meaning has extended to mean "view/sight/scenery" in modern Korean, Japanese, and Chinese, and this extension happened very early on.

구경 is already attested in Middle Korean as 구겨ᇰ〮. It is [believed to derive](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/0734e40329dd4e549b06a82b3c12c4c8) from a hanja-based collocation 求景 = search + view/sight/scenery = sightseeing. This is not used in modern Chinese at all, nor in modern Japanese.